# Saving photos to DCIM/Camera - why aren't they showing up in Photos app?

Tags: android, camera

I've got a custom camera app.

I'm saving the images (after doing some processing) using a FOS, writing the jpeg bytes I've gotten after using OpenCV `Mat`s to manipulate the image:

```
File photo=new File(dir, getFileName()); // [external_storage]/DCIM/Camera/id.jpg
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
fos.write(jpeg[0]);
fos.close();
```

Using a file manager, I can see that the images are saved correctly to the `DCIM/Camera` directory, along with photos taken using the Google camera app. However they are not shown in the Photos app on the phone. Do I need to set some kind of EXIF data for this to happen, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the photo has been saved, add this line to let the Photos app know there are new photos:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + photo.getAbsolutePath())));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is being missed is that the gallery is not refreshed after saving the files.

here is a small snippet

```
sendStickyBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

and add permisions in androidmanifest.xml